# How to add extension attributes to Product Model and Collection

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

At `PriceRenderer` we have `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox::getSaleableItem`

It returns `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface` which is implemented in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`.

Question is how to add Extension Attribute to this model to be visible at `SaleableItem`?

At repository it works perfect with `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`. But here if i go to `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox::getSaleableItem`, extension attributes are empty.

Comment: Can you show how extension attributes are being applied to products?

Comment: Let say „standard way” :) like here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html . So it’s afterGet() and afterGetList() plugins. It worka if collection goes from ProductRepositoryInterface. But if you load product by model or by collection, it work’s not.

Comment: Right, the guide does not show all the ways a product model instance may be hydrated, only basic examples on the repository. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you could try to set plugin on the **getExtensionAttributes** method of the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` directly or set plugin on the **getSaleableItem** method of the `Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox` and install an extension attribute there.

First things first we need to declare `extension_attributes.xml` file:

```xml
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
    <attribute code="test_ext_attr" type="int"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

Plugin on the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` (`di.xml` file):

```xml
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="set_test_ext_attr_plugin"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SetTestExtAttr"
            sortOrder="20"/>
</type>
```

After plugin implementation:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterfaceFactory;

class SetTestExtAttr
{
    private ProductExtensionInterfaceFactory $extensionAttributesFactory;

    public function __construct(ProductExtensionInterfaceFactory $extensionAttributesFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionAttributesFactory = $extensionAttributesFactory;
    }

    public function afterGetExtensionAttributes(
        Product $subject,
        ?ProductExtensionInterface $result
    ): ?ProductExtensionInterface {
        if (null === $result) {
            $result = $this->extensionAttributesFactory->create();
        }

        $result->setTestExtAttr(2222);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And then you can access declared extension attribute from the `Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox::getSaleableItem`:

[image: Dump and die result of the getExtensionAttributes in getSaleableItem method]
[image: Dumped result on the frontend]

Comment: Thanks. That works. I resolved this issue another way. With catalog_product_collection_load_after observer. Now I think witch solution is better in case of performance. As extension attribute I use interface with some methods inside, so there is no additional call to DB at this point. Yours solution with plugin on getExtensionAttributes() looks more strict. And here we don't have additional foreach like in collection.

Comment: Now i checked, that if we add this plugin here, it seams that we don't need plugin for ProductRepositoryInterface::get() and ProductRepositoryInterface::getList() like is described in https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/add-attributes/ . And again, I think that with this solution we have better perfomance than iterating foreach in afterGetList plugin. Am i right about that? If yes why adobe chose to show in docs this solution with repositories and afterGet() and afterGetList()? I didn't checked that from api site.

Comment: I checked API. And if we add plugin on Product::getExtensionAttributes we will get extension attribute in collection, in product repository but it will be not added by API call. To get extensionAttribute at API /V1/products we have to add this plugin to ProductRepositoryInterface. It's confusing.

Comment: @Sebas, not sure what is the difference in our actions, but I am getting the extension attribute from the API call with solution above. I double checked, maybe I have another plugin on ``ProductRepositoryInterface`` which triggers plugin declared on the ``getExtensionAttributes`` and there is no another plugins.

Comment: That's strange. My type of extension_attribute is Interface that have some methods that returns value. What kind of extension attribute you have? Primitive type like string, int or some object? Strange :) .

Comment: @Sebas, I have ``int`` type attribute, I will check with some complex type and will return with feedback

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing: we can use plugin on `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getExtensionAttribute` to add extension attribute to collection, model and ProductRepositoryInterface. It will be available in code from admin or frontend area. If we would like to add it in web-api, we have to add plugin at ProductRepositoryInterface.

To prevent unnecessary duble add of this extension attribute at `ProductRepositoryInterface::getList` after plugin, if we add also "after" plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getExtensionAttribute` we should check is this extension attribute already set. Because if we call that method for code at frontend area, this will be set by `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getExtensionAttribute`. Here is fragment of my code:
[image: afterGetList()]

As you can see at line 82 I check is my extension attribute is already set. Because if it will be called from code front or admin area, this will be already set. But if it will be called from web_api area, it will be null so it has to be set.